# Using HttpResponse from threads

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, httpresponse

I have been stuck on this problem for a while and have been doing some reading but i am not sure how to solve this issue.

My application is a web based c# asp.net.
I followed [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/642773/AJAX-Progress-Bar?fid=1840574) to give a progress bar for the long process handled by my application.
At the end of the process the user is prompted to save a file that the application has generated.

This used to work fine before i added the progress bar functionality as in the tutorial. The problem is that i am trying to use HttpContext.Current.Response to generate the response for the end user to save the file **from a thread**. Here is some of the code.

```
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var progress = ProgressBar1.Progress;            
        SynchronizationContext uiContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        saveContext = Context;
        Thread thread = new Thread(() => start(progress));
        thread.Start();
        Button2.Enabled = false;
    }
```

And then the start(progress method does most of the work and uses progress.SetProgress(currentProgress++ / maxProgress) to update the progress bar which works fine. 
The issue arises at the end when i try to send the httresponse from the thread.

```
     private void start(Progress progress)
     {
         //do all the work here on the file. 
         // updates the progress bar as the file processing progresses

         //code to prompt the user to save the file.
         var fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(filePath);            
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename=\"{0}\"", ".docx"));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileInfo.Length.ToString());            
        HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(filePath);
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

The Http.ContextCurrent gives a null value. 
how do I send a response from the thread? 
Or how do I send the response after the thread is complete from the original thread?

- I tried to use SynchronisationContext but also couldn't figure it out.
- I tried a few other thing like saving the http context from the original thread and using it in the thread but also didn't work.

Any tips/hints or code would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: do not update progressbar in another thread,i dont know your design but or call this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(yourmethod)) where that method will run on the UI thread and safelly update progressbar,or create another aproach using delegates or the backgroundworker...

Comment: I'd have the user specify the file path at the start if possible (better UX).  I'd update the progressbar with BeginInvoke.